# Vector maths is off in one of the functions

Tags: javascript, math, vector, p5.js

I intend to simulate gravitational acceleration on a 2D plane (simplified, no gravitational constant). My code is interpreted without any error in the console, but instead of having the two circles slowly accelerate towards each other, they go away from each other. Acceleration seems to stay at 0. I can't understand this behaviour.

```
// orbiters is gonna be the array containing the two celestial bodies 
var orbiters;
var sun;
var earth;
function setup() {
  frameRate(.3);
  console.log("starting the program")
  createCanvas(640, 480);
  sun = new Orbiter(10, 0, 0, width/2, height/2);
  earth = new Orbiter (1, 0, 0, width/5, height/4);
  orbiters = [sun, earth];
}

function draw() {
  console.log("starting the loop")
  background(15, 40, 20);
  // [missing: calculate gravity acceleration], then update position, display position. 
  orbiters.forEach(function(celBody) { 
    celBody.update();
    })
  orbiters.forEach(function(celBody) { 
    celBody.display();
    })
    // for each celestial body, accelerate it towards every other celestial body
  orbiters.forEach(function(celBody){
    orbiters.forEach(function (otherCelBody){
      if(celBody != otherCelBody){
        celBody.gravityAccelerate(otherCelBody.weight, otherCelBody.pos)
      }
    })
  })
}
// No volume for now: describe a body with weight, velocity, position
function Orbiter(weight, vx, vy, posx, posy) {
  this.weight = weight;
  this.pos = createVector(posx, posy);
  this.vel = createVector(vx, vy);
  this.acc = createVector(0, 0);
  
  //this finds an acceleration and an angle and gives out a vector to accelerate a body by
  this.gravityAccelerate = function(otherBodyWeight, otherBodyPosition) {
    
    // calculate magnitude
    gravDistance = sqrt(sq(otherBodyPosition.x - this.pos.x)+sq(otherBodyPosition.y - this.pos.y));
    // calculate angle
    gravHeading = createVector(otherBodyPosition.sub(this.pos)).heading();
    // calculate force and divide by own mass(acceleration amount)
    gravForce = (this.weight * otherBodyWeight) / gravDistance;
// calculate gravitational acceleration's magnitude as a vector
    gravAccMag = gravForce / this.weight;
    // apply amount to angle and give a vector
    console.log("gravity acceleration = ")
    gravAccVec = createVector(Math.cos(gravHeading), Math.sin(gravHeading));
// display gravitational acceleration vector
    console.log(gravAccVec.x);
    console.log(gravAccVec.y);
    console.log("this body's acceleration = ");
    console.log(this.acc.x);
    console.log(this.acc.y);
    this.acc = this.acc.add(gravAccVec);
    console.log("this body's position")
    console.log(this.pos.x)
    console.log(this.pos.x)
  }
  
  this.update = function() {
    this.vel.add(this.acc);
    this.pos.add(this.vel);
  }
  
  this.display = function() {
    this.size = sqrt(this.weight * 10);
    fill (60, 180, 70);
    ellipse(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.size, this.size);
  }
}
```

I tried lowering the framerate to better analyze the execution, the initial position of the two circles seems correct. They appear to be repulsed away instead of attracted, and what's even stranger, I see the change in position but total acceleration (this.acc) and gravitational acceleration variation (gravAccVec) have a value of 0 and don't change, and the heading of the gravity acceleration vector is `null`, so I don't understand what causes the repulsive motion. Changing the weight value doesn't impact the outcome, and even switching sine and cosine for the evaluation of the angle of the gravity vector doesn't change anything:

```
body1(x,y)  body2(x,y)
320,240     -192,-120
512,360     -704,-480
1216,840    -1920,-1320
3136,2160   -5056,-3480
```

To execute this code you'll need to import the p5.js library.

Comment: Your comment says `accelerate it towards every other celestial body` but your code doesn't do that :) you need to insert `if (celBody != otherCelBody)`

Comment: You're right, I've corrected this, the behavior is still crazy but I see it has changed

Comment: It's wrong to expect that anyone will run your code to find out what your mistake is.  I'd recommend that you fire up a debugger and figure out where you went wrong.  How's your physics background?  Do you have unit tests for these functions?

Comment: Gravity is an attractive force.  You should check your signs.

Comment: I found an error: `a.sub(b)` subtracts b from a, which means when calculating the heading you also changed the position. You need `gravHeading = p5.Vector.sub(otherBodyPosition, this.pos).heading();`

Comment: I did that @duffymo, and in fact no acceleration at all is applied to the objects. I think Chris G might have nailed it, need to check it as soon as my work day is over

Comment: I spent a bunch of time to fix this and here's the result: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/un20ejvm/ (change the initial y velocity for earth to 0.8 to get a circular orbit) ((not posting an answer because it's basically the above sub error & the rest is math))

Comment: Chris you rock! Thank you thank you thank you. Once I scale this up it'll be a humble contribution to what has been done in p5 :) and I'll credit you for your help <3